# gcc compiler linking differently on two servers

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a large source-controlled C++ codebase which compiles and links without error on one Linux server.

I am now trying to set up the same application on a new server, so have checked out the same code on a new box.

However, when I execute an identical make command on identical code on this new box, I get errors. The cause appears to be because on the old box, shared library (.so) files are created. On the new box - which is using identical code and therefore makefiles - makes static libraries (.a).

The compiler being used appears to be the same as well - gcc-3.4.6.

Obviously, I have some config set differently somewhere but can anyone advise or where this config might be? I can't think of any small change which would cause this effect.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the linker `ld` is part of `binutils`, which is delivered with the standard binaries as part of the Unix distribution you have, and is **not** part of the `gcc` suite.

Therefore, when you get from an old server to a new server, chances are that you pass from an old `ld` to a new `ld`.

Since a library is first created by the linker, it would be interested to check it out.

Note that if you suspect the compiler (since it performs the call to `ld`), you can write a `ld` executable script that just echoes the arguments it receives and then calls the real `ld` behind the scenes (meddling with `$PATH` should get you going).

It sounds natural that it is either a case of different arguments (why ?) or a different binray, figure out which and you'll be one step closer to solving your issue.

Comment: agreed, but I tend to believe that the fact that a given library is built as a static `libfoo.a` or as a dynamic `libfoo.so` don't depend much on the version of binutils (or even of gcc); it is more a `configure` or `Makefile` issue of that `-lfoo`library at its build time.

Answer (score 1):

`configure` stuff might have generated slightly different `Makefile`-s.

And when you link with `-lfoo`, the linker first try dynamic `libfoo.so` then static `libfoo.a`.

**GCC is now at version 4.6.2** so your *3.4.6* version is very old. Consider upgrading it, because GCC has made a lot of progress since.

Try using `gcc -v` (perhaps as `make CC='gcc -v'`) to understand what is going on when building.

And give much more detail if you want real help. What are the actual libraries involved?